# Restart Android Studio programmatically

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I have to invalidate cache and Restart Android Studio programmatically, is it possible?

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

After many research i am able to perform this task using intelliG idea

```
ApplicationEx app = 

(ApplicationEx)ApplicationManager.getApplication();  // creating an object of ApplicationEx class

     boolean canRestart = app.isRestartCapable();  // Checking whether able to restart or not

    if(canRestart)
    {
      app.restart(true);  // restart
   }
```